# How to Map Array values from one Array to Another Array JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

This is my Code. Where I want to Pass the Values of `kvArray` to Second Array.

```
var kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10}, 
               {key: 2, value: 20}, 
               {key: 3, value: 30}];

var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj => { 
   var payload = {};
   payload["rt"];
   payload["do"];
   payload["f1"];
   payload[obj.key] = obj.value;
   console.log(payload["rt"]);
   return payload;
});
```

The `console.log` is coming `undefined`. 
Can anyone help here? I am pretty new to Map function.

I want to Print this result.

```
 payload["do"]=10
 payload["f1"]=20
 payload["f2"]=30
```

Comment: You are assigning payload[1], payload[2] and payload[3] when you are referring to obj.key in your map function. Thus payload["rt"] remains undefined.

Comment: what value you want to store in **payload["rt"]** ?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: @NullPointer i want payload["rt"] = 10.

Comment: btw, it's quite unclear, if the wanted keys depends on the index or on the key values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10}, 
               {key: 2, value: 20}, 
               {key: 3, value: 30}];

var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj =>{ 
   var payload = {};
   const mapping = [null, 'rt', 'do', 'f1']; 
   const key = mapping[obj.key];
   payload[key] = obj.value;
   return payload;
});
console.log(reformattedArray);
```

Comment: this is helpful:). thank you so much.  Just to pass the keys of 'rt','do' to the payload, it is better to map them by declaring them in another array. thats sweet :)

Comment: `const mapping = [null, 'rt', 'do', 'f1'];` what is null for?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and build a new object with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

For the final keys, you could use an object `keys` with corresopnding keys to the the keys of the given object.

```js
var kvArray = [{ key: 1, value: 10 }, { key: 2, value: 20 }, { key: 3, value: 30 }],
    keys = { 1: 'rt', 2: 'do', 3: 'fi' },
    result = kvArray.map(({ key, value }) => ({ [keys[key]]: value }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what format you want.

try the code below：

```
var kvArray = [{ key: 1, value: 10 },
  { key: 2, value: 20 },
  { key: 3, value: 30 }];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj => obj.value);
console.log(reformattedArray)
```

the result will be:

```
[ 10, 20, 30 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with lines:

```
payload["rt"];
payload["do"];
payload["f1"];
```

If you want to create new keys in the reformatterArray, try assigning a value, eg.

```
var kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10}, 
           {key: 2, value: 20}, 
           {key: 3, value: 30}];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj =>{ 
   var payload = {};
   payload["rt"] = "";
   payload["do"]= "";
   payload["f1"]= "";
   payload[obj.key] = obj.value;
   console.log(payload["rt"]);
   return payload;
});

console.log(reformattedArray):
//result
0: {1: 10, rt: "", do: "", f1: ""}
1: {2: 20, rt: "", do: "", f1: ""}
2: {3: 30, rt: "", do: "", f1: ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were assigning the value to payload but getting the values of payload.

```js
  var kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10}, 
               {key: 2, value: 20}, 
               {key: 3, value: 30}];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj =>{ 
   var payload = {};
   payload[obj.key] = obj.value;
  console.log(payload[obj.key]);
   return payload;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping data to reformattedArray , so you need to pring reformattedArray to get values,

```js
   var kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10}, 
               {key: 2, value: 20}, 
               {key: 3, value: 30}];
var reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj =>{ 
   var payload = {};
   payload[obj.key] = obj.value;
   return payload;
});

  console.log(reformattedArray);
```

Also you have following code which is of no use

> payload["rt"];
>      payload["do"];
>      payload["f1"];

Comment: i have defined the keys of the array payload. and i want this output payload["rt"] = 10. like this.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine

```
let kvArray = [{key: 1, value: 10},
           {key: 2, value: 20},
           {key: 3, value: 30}];

let reformattedArray = kvArray.map(obj =>{
   var payload = {};
   payload[obj.key] = obj.value;
   return payload;
});

console.log(reformattedArray)
```

The above code print output like this

```
[
  0: {1: 10}
  1: {2: 20}
  2: {3: 30}
]
```

For more info, refer this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)